# How to display custom list activity in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to display data in list activity. How do I achieve this?

---

TITLE                    Date

### Sub Title                Button

TITLE                    Date

### Sub Title                Button

TITLE                    Date

### Sub Title                Button

.
.
.
.
and so on

Does a tutorial exist related to custom list activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this [free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that covers the process of creating custom list rows.